# Why are both tv_sec and tv_usec significant in determining the duration of a timer?

Tags: c, timer

The manual page getitimer(2) claims that

> both tv_sec and tv_usec significant in determining the
>   duration of a timer

It doesn't go on to say why that is. In many examples that I have come across tv_sec is simply set to 0, while tv_usec is given some reasonable value, or vis versa. Are these timers counting down simultaneously, or is the total countdown time tv_sec + tv_usec? Should I use both? Neither?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setitimer.2.html) documents the `timeval` structure:

```
struct timeval {
    long tv_sec;                /* seconds */
    long tv_usec;               /* microseconds */
};
```

If you want to wait a whole number of seconds, you'd just set `tv_sec`. If you want to wait a portion of a second, you'd set `tv_usec`. If you want to wait 4.5 seconds, you'd set *both* of them to appropriate values (4 and 500000, respectively)

Comment: Also, is usec not allowed to exceed 1 second?

Comment: POSIX does not seem to specify any behavior for all the corner cases (tv_usec < 0, tv_nsec < 0, tv_usec > 1000000, tv_nsec > 1000000000), so it's best to not even let that happen.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the total time is the sum of both. tv_sec is the seconds. And tv_usec is microseconds beyond that.

Comment: so for example if I gave them values of 1 and 250000 respectively, that would be 1.25 seconds?

Answer (score 3):

The structure is described though:

```
struct timeval {
    long tv_sec;                /* seconds */
    long tv_usec;               /* microseconds */
};
```

As you see, the total time is `tv_sec + (1.0/1000000) * tv_usec` seconds. That's why when you need times under a second you set `tv_usec`, when you need times over 1sec you set both (but usually end up setting only `tv_sec`)

Comment: [Perhaps](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setitimer.2.html) `time_t      tv_sec;  suseconds_t tv_usec;`?

Answer (score 0):

> long int tv_usec This is the rest of the elapsed time (a fraction of a
>   second), represented as the number of microseconds. It is always less
>   than one million.

tv_sec will handle the full seconds, while tv_usec handles the microseconds.

The microseconds will reset back to 0 when it get to its max (1 million) and increments the seconds just like a normal stopwatch.

Answer (score -2):

I've had a memory leak because of that I didn't set tv_usec. Comuter takes a sum of those two values and if you not initialize one of them the sum value could be random.